# How to log into a website using iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication

This question seems to have been asked but without enough results for me.  I have a website where user's can log in.  I'd like to make an app that would allow them to log in without using Safari.

Say the website is "http://www.website.com/login.aspx". I know that the user name field in java is "Login1_UserName" and the password name field is "Login1_Password".  I would like to set up a custom webview that would pass the credentials along and then populate the view with the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ASIHTTPRequest` is deprecated, but it includes [`ASIFormDataRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#sending_a_form_post_with_ASIFormDataRequest) for making `POST` web requests, like your authentication form. You can parse the response to deal with authentication tokens. There are other classes people are writing to make web requests a bit easier ([example](https://github.com/gowalla/AFNetworking#readme)).

Whether you use `UITextField` instances in a table view, or a web form in a local `UIWebView` to handle the authentication page is up to you.

Comment: NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.website.com/login.aspx"

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setPostValue:@"name" forKey:@"Login1_UserName"];

[request setPostValue:@"password" forKey:@"Login1_Password"];